# Wordpress : URL error 404 but the page exists

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, url-routing, http-status-code-404

I moved my wordpress (3.0) blog to my dedicaced server.

Just one thing is broken :

if i set the url in worpress to be

```
http://wwww.example.com/page?id=3
```

**The page is correctly shown**

If i set the URL to be :

```
http://wwww.example.com/about/
http://www.example.com/services/
```

**it ends up with a 404 not found page !!**

Here's my virtual host if it helps :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   ServerName www.example.fr

    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    <Directory /var/www/example>
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>


    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-example.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-example.log
    ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks you

Comment: Sounds like a mod_rewrite issue - are you using wordpress permalinks?  Have you checked in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wordpress uses .htaccess to do its redirections, have you tried changing the `AllowOverride None` directive to `AllowOverride All` ?

Comment: I just tried AllowOverride All and it works perfeclty ! thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your new server isn't set up to rewrite your URLs to pretty links. You basically want to follow the guidelines on this setup page:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Answer (score 0):

I've found that one thing to watch for — quite aside from a correctly configured .htaccess, httpd-vhosts.conf etc — is to check that mod_rewrite is enabled in your server's http.conf. Just ensure that this line is uncommented:

LoadModule rewrite_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so